# Drupal 9 - Unable to install package with composer

Tags: drupal

How can I add a new package to the vendor folder by using the composer. I tried to use the composer command `composer require [package-name]`. However, I tried but I was getting an error telling me "./compose.json" is not a UTF-8. After several attempts to configure some PHP options and execute the same command, the package was downloaded, but in a different path than the drupal-9.x.x/vendor/package-name-folder path. But there is another path inside the drupal-9.x.x/core folder. The package name is included in the composer.json file in the drupal-9.x.x/core folder path.

The question here is how can I insert a new package using the composer command into the Drupal project, and is it possible to link this package to a custom module so that it is from the installation dependencies?

Comment: How did you start your project? Did you use [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project) as it outlines in the [Starting a Site Using Drupal Composer Project Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/starting-a-site-using-drupal-composer-project-templates) documentation? When you require a drupal module via composer, you prefix the module name with "drupal/". eg. `composer require drupal/pathauto`

Comment: Also, try running `composer validate` to check your composer.json file is ok. Also, I forgot to mention that drupal/recommended-project is what sets up  the paths for where drupal modules and themes will be downloaded to when running composer require.

Comment: Is it a Drupal Module or External Package? 

What you mean by linking the package to custom module. The package will be autoloaded by Composer and it should be available anywhere in your application by importing the corresponding classes with `use` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem seems to be related to eclipse ide and trying to open the composer .json file through the ide and using the ide options to download and install the package

What I did was use the git bash and I executed the composer command and the package was downloaded as required